# strings invalidated after parser finished, iphone

Tags: iphone, nsxmlparser

I've parsed an xml and stored the parsed data on strings which are property declared, retained and synthesized, the values are getting into these strings during parsing, but are being invalidated after the parser finish parsing. I'm not able to access them from another IBAction method, where i get EXEC BAD ACCESS error, which, from my experiences, think that arises when the debugger is accessing an invalidated memory.

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{            
//NSLog(@"found this element: %@", elementName);
currentElement = [elementName copy];
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"resp"]) {
    // clear out our story item caches...
}
else if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"org"]) {
    name = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"fileid"];
    extention = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"extension"];
    NSLog(@"image named %@ of type %@",name,extention);
}
else if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"photo"]) {
    photoid = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"photoid"];
    NSLog (@"photo id = %@",photoid);
}
```

}

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {
    //NSLog(@"found characters: %@", string);
    // save the characters for the current item...
    if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"userid"]) {
        userid =[NSString stringWithString:string];
        NSLog (@"user id = %@",userid);
        } 
    else if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"albumid"]) {
        albumid =[NSString stringWithString:string];
        NSLog (@"album id = %@",albumid);
    }
}
```

This portion is working fine, but

```
- (IBAction)download {
    NSString *urlstr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://staging-data.mysite.com/%@/albumphoto/%@/%@/%@.%@",userid,albumid,photoid,name,extention];
    NSLog(urlstr);
    NSURL *url= [NSURL URLWithString:urlstr];
    NSData *imgdata = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:imgdata];
    newImage.image=img;
    [imgdata release];

}
```

This results in error. pls help

Comment: please include your output, log, and the actual error message and line it occurs on, to help us diagnose the problem.  Also try to reduce the example to the smallest one that shows the error, for example, if you don't save the string 'photo' and just supply something you know to be a good value in the URL, does it still crash?

Comment: if i give values to the string, hardcoded inside the action method, it is not crashing. So the problem is surely that those strings are becoming nil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you look carefully at this line:

```
name = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"fileid"];
```

Which sets an attribute to an `NSString` owned by the XML parser without copying it, retaining it etc.  I suggest you take a copy, and retain that.

My concern is that when the XML parser goes away, it takes the `name` string with it, along with `extension` and `photoid`.

Comment: retaining is what required, thnx

Comment: Don't forget to release it when needed!

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement this method also to know when an end tag is encountered.

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName

Comment: is that compulsary, i've included that one,but there's nothing inside it, an empty one.

Comment: yes ,this is a delegate method which will inform the parser that it  moves to the end of the element.And it shouldn't be empty If you encounter the an element, you have to add the object to any array.

Comment: Implement this delegate method also to know errors encountered by the parser.
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser parseErrorOccurred:(NSError *)parseError

Comment: i've used them all, but didn't shown here as it is not relevant,